# Android - Activity vs FragmentActivity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

I am new in Android. I want to build an app with tab format. I found many documentation where `Activity` has been used. Also in many cases have used `FragmentActivity`. I am not sure which will be better to start. Please suggest me should I use `Activity` or `FragmentActivity` to start development in tab format?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

[ianhanniballake is right](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15318582/7487335). You can get all the functionality of `Activity` from `FragmentActivity`. In fact, [`FragmentActivity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html) has more functionality.

Using `FragmentActivity` you can easily build `tab and swap` format. For each tab you can use different `Fragment` (`Fragments` are reusable). So for any `FragmentActivity` you can reuse the same `Fragment`.

Still you can use `Activity` for single pages like list down something and edit element of the list in next page.

Also remember to use `Activity` if you are using `android.app.Fragment`; use `FragmentActivity` if you are using `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`. Never attach a `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` to an `android.app.Activity`, as this will cause an exception to be thrown.

Comment: FYI, I found some good discussions about Fragment Android in another language here [Fragment trong Android](http://www.umbalaaz.com/threads/cach-su-dung-fragment-trong-android.336/)

Comment: BUT see @ianhanniballake's answer:  *unless targeting API's older than API 11*, you can use `Activity` instead of `FragmentActivity`, and still have access to Fragments; *this* answer doesn't quite say that (though the last paragraph implies that).

Comment: As we know, mostly we have a BaseActivity in our project, and all the other activities will extend it.But when comes to FragmentActivity, we can't do it. So I don't use FragmentActivity even in the case of tab.

Answer (score 58):

`FragmentActivity` gives you all of the functionality of `Activity` plus the ability to use [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) which are very useful in many cases, particularly when working with the [ActionBar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html), which is the best way to use Tabs in Android.

If you are **only** targeting Honeycomb (v11) or greater devices, then you can use `Activity` and use the native Fragments introduced in v11 without issue. `FragmentActivity` was built specifically as part of the [Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html) to back port some of those useful features (such as Fragments) back to older devices.

I should also note that you'll probably find the [Backward Compatibility - Implementing Tabs](http://developer.android.com/training/backward-compatible-ui/abstracting.html) training very helpful going forward.

Comment: @A--C - I've edited my answer - you are correct that API 11+ devices can use native Fragments and the normal Activity class.

Comment: I'm going to challenge the assertion that the normal Activity class can be used as a Fragment in API11+. This appears to have changed in KitKat. See https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/kitkat-mr1-release/core/java/android/app/Fragment.java#584

Comment: @cmarcelk - not sure what 'the normal Activity class can be used as a Fragment' means - I said that `android.app.Activity` works with `android.app.Fragment`, not anything about them being interchangeable.

Comment: @cmarcelk in API11+ `Activity` can *access* fragments; `FragmentActivity` is no longer required. Activity or FragmentActivity are not themselves Fragments.

Answer (score 3):

If you use the Eclipse "New Android Project" wizard in a recent ADT bundle, you'll automatically get tabs implemented as a Fragments. This makes the conversion of your application to the tablet format much easier in the future.

For simple single screen layouts you may still use `Activity`.