# Dynamic way of using fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

### [I am referring to this video tutorial here ---- CLICK HERE](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aSRJynmOvFo)

---

I the video the speaker is using a code below

---

He is using dynamic way of dealing with fragments

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.simpledynamicfragment;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.Fragment;

import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
        FragmentActivity frag=new FragmentActivity();
        FragmentManager FM = getSupportFragmentManager();       
        
        
    }


}
```

I am getting the error at line ::

```
FragmentManager FM = getSupportFragmentManager();
```

- I know we need to extend fragment class but in the video the speaker
  uses extending the activity. How is he accomplishing the task without
  encountering errors.

**Or**

- am i doing the mistake

**Note**:: I am using support package for fragments

**ERROR**:: `The method getSupportFragmentManager() is undefined for the type MainActivity`

**How to clarify & clear my doubts .... Any guidance would e helpful**

Comment: what error do you get? Using an activity as host for the fragments is correct so far. And why not extending with FragmentActivity?

Comment: @ bofredo ...... I get the error as ..... The method getSupportFragmentManager() is undefined for the type MainActivity

Comment: have you tried changing the extending to FragmentActivity?

Comment: I am trying it now ... Please check that video link .... how speaker is accomplishing that

Comment: Also do we need fragmentActivity for backward compatibility .... speaker in the video looks he is using API >11 ... i am using lower level API

Comment: Speaker not build project, if he build and run — got same error.

Comment: adding the package android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity .... cleared the error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please, replace `extends Activity` to `extends FragmentActivity`, this help.

EDIT:

Speaker on video not build project, if he build and run, he will got same error.

Comment: Can't we use extends Activity to host fragments ..... please check that video in the tutorial ?

Comment: It may be error, you try use method **getSupportFragmentManager** which located only in **FragmentActivity**, look this link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html

Comment: I think u need Fragment Activity for backward compatibility issues. Moreover you  have more functionality. Check this StackO [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15318518/android-activity-vs-fragmentactivity

Comment: @kvirair ..... I cleared the error ... the support package ....android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity .... was missing from the class here .... your link helped me cleared the error ..... May be the speaker might be using API>11 ... so he might not got the error

Comment: the guy in the tutorial doesn't use the support-library. i guess that is the reason why he can extend just with the "Activity".

Comment: @smriti3 Framgents are from api level 11. if you need backward compatibility use `SupportFragment` in which case you need to extend FragmentActivity. If you min sdk is 11 and above use Fragment and extend Activity

Comment: @ Raghunandan ..... Yes(my APK is below 11) but still we can use extend activity ..... But we have to import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity .... i checked and it works like this ..... also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15318518/android-activity-vs-fragmentactivity  link helped me figure it out :)

Comment: @ Raghunandan ..... Because  android.app.Activity ---- extends------  android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity