# Android Fragments : support library crashes on extending Activity class

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am learning android development right now and i came across the fragment class.

Here I found out that we can use two imports for the Fragment Class, namely

1. ***android.support.v4.app.Fragment*** : Can be used for API < 11 as well.
2. **android.app.Fragment** : Used for API >= 11 ONLY.

However I found that when I use **support fragment** in an activity, it crashes when I extend the **Activity** class. The Support Fragment works fine when I extend **FragmentActivity** or **ActionbarActivity.**

Please help me understand why does this happen.

Comment: Its easy `ActionbarActivity` extends `FragmentActivty` which are made to deal with the `fragments` but activity is the basic kind of activity its mainly made for one view kind of things, also you don't have `getSupportFragmentManager` in the normal `Activity` which deals with the `android.support.v4.app.Fragment ` also refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15318518/android-activity-vs-fragmentactivity for more info on the subject

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to choose whether you use classes from the support library or not. If you do, you have to use classes that are compatible with each other. `FragmentActivity` and `ActionBarActivity` are part of the support library, hence they support `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`. `Activity` is not from the support lib, so it supports `android.app.Fragment`.

Basically, `Activity` and `ActionBarActivity` do the same things. There are minor differences between the 2, the main one being the method `getFragmentManager()` in `Activity` being replaced by `getSupportFragmentManager()` in the support library. Other methods that differ are usually prefixed with 'support' in `ActionBarActivity`.

Comment: Sorry I cant upvote your answer because of low rep. Thanks for the help. Please tell me one more thing. What is better to use ? My personal opinion is that I should use the native library as mostly all the phones in the world right now are having API >=11. Please correct me if you think I am wrong.

Comment: Glad I could help, don't worry about the vote, I don't do this for reputation ;) Which you should use mainly depends on details, for example if you need to use nested fragments, it's API 17+ or support lib. You would also have to consider your market : are your (future) users from a market where Android 2.3 still sees some use ? If so, no way around the support lib. Related links [here](https://www.google.be/search?q=support%20library%20vs%20normal).