# Adding activities dynamically

Tags: android, android-activity

**Few details about my code:**

I get a `JSONObject`, then I get the strings from it and using the field `"name"`, I create as many `buttons` as `fields` are there in the `json`.

Now, the thing is I want to add functionality to the `buttons` too and I am not sure if it will work this way.

Check my code please, I ll comment where I am stuck.

```
for(int i=0; i<arr.length();i++){

    JSONObject oneObject = arr.getJSONObject(i);

    id = oneObject.getString("Id");
    nume = oneObject.getString("Nume");

    Button btn = new Button(context);
    btn.setId(i);
    btn.setText(nume);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        //STUCK HERE!

        }
    });

    ll.addView(btn);
}
```

So, for each `button`, I want to make a new activity, so a new `intent`, because each `button` will need a new `"screen"`(or so to say).

Is there any ways I can actually do this ,or it's impossible?

**NOTE:** I could not find anything like this over the internet and my thoughts on this is that it's impossible, but I wanted a few more opinions before I move on.

Comment: Activities are tied to the AndoidManifest.xml file aren't they? This looks like a typical Fragment solvable question IMHO.

Comment: Yes indeed they are AndroidManifset bound.Anyways, as far as I understand, it's impossible to do that.How would you do it with fragments anyways?I have worked with fragments too and I highly doubt it will work as you need to create a new xml layout and a new java class for each fragment...

Comment: Well, you'd just need a generic Fragment class that takes in some variables through its constructor. You don't need a new class for each one. It would always have the same layout unless you could send some json to distinguish styles, but that's not a problem - you can load different styles for the Fragment when you create it.

Comment: That means my mainactivity will implement Fragment,right? So that I can make the transitions...?

Comment: No, you'd have it extend FragmentActivity so that it can hold Fragments. Then you could use transitions to add/remove Fragments on the fly, making it look to the user like you're changing Activity.

Comment: Ok that does make sense.I haven't used FragmentActivity, I usually go with Activity ,anyways, I guess I can handle this task with the information you gave.Feel free to give an answer and after I get some documentation checked, to make sure this is what I need,I ll check your answer as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like we said in the comments, dynamically creating Activities won't work because you can't modify the AndroidManifest.xml at runtime. Instead, this problem is ideally suited to [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).

You could use a standard Activity rather than FragmentActivity, but [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15318518/android-activity-vs-fragmentactivity) a reason why I think you shouldn't. Then you just use that as your root activity and in your onClicks add Fragments programatically:

```
FragmentManager fragMan = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragTransaction = fragMan.beginTransaction();

Fragment fragment = new ImageFragment();
fragTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
fragTransaction.commit();
```

There's a nice guide on all that stuff [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html).

Comment: I have not tested it yet ,but it is what I need ,I am fairly sure about it.I will check the answer and give a thumbs.Thanks for the suggestions and the actual answer.