# How to launch a fragment activity from MainActivity?

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

I have built a navigation drawer. Once the app launches I direct the user from "MainActivity" to MainMenuActivity through an intent through the following code inside "MainActivity":

```
    Intent Activity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainMenuActivity.class);
    startActivity(Activity);
```

but when the app launches, it crashes directly with a logcat of:

```
Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {package.allineed/Package.MainMenuActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

I declared MainMenuActivity inside AndroidManifest.xml by adding to the application the following code:

```
    <activity android:name=".MainMenuActivity"></activity>
```

but the app crashed and gave me the following logcat:

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{..allineed/...allineed.MainMenuActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: ...allineed.MainMenuActivity cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
```

This is is MainMenuActivity:

```
public class MainMenuActivity extends Fragment{
View myView;


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     myView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main_menu,container,false);

    return myView;
}
}
```

I consumed a lot of time on it, ho possibly could it be solved?

Comment: have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: ``MainMenuActivity`` is a fragment  not `Activity` , you have to decide you want an `Activity` or `Fragment`

Comment: Do you want a Fragment or an Activity?

Comment: I want to access a fragment from an activity

Comment: then you have to add a frame layout in your acitivity layout and load the fragment  using `FragmentManager`

Comment: google "load Fragment in an Activity"

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
public class MainMenuActivity extends FragmentActivity
```

you can take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15318518/android-activity-vs-fragmentactivity) for more information.

You have to embed the fragment inside an existing activity, you can never directly call `startActivity()` on a fragment class

Answer (score 0):

First of all `MainMenuActivity` is a `Fragment` not an `Activity`. So shouldn't declare in `Manifest.xml` as an `Activity`.

And you can not directly call `Fragment` using Intent.

By using `FragmentManager` and `FragmentTransaction` you can load fragment into the activity.

Just check this link on How to use fragment in activity?

> http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/12/programmatically-add-fragment.html

Answer (score 0):

if you want a NavigationDrawer, then you main_activity.xml should see as folowed

```xml
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

then you can set your navigation in MainActivity via

```
Fragment fragment = new MainMenuActivity();

// Insert the fragment by replacing any existing fragment
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
     .replace(R.id.left_drawer, fragment)
     .commit();
```

`FrameLayout` is a holder, that you can fill with any layout in runtime.
The last item in `DrawerLayout` is ever used for navigation. with `android:layout_gravity` you can say, where you want the navigation.