# BaseFragmentActivityApi16.startActivityForResult(intent, int, Bundle) throwing error when targeting Android O

Tags: android

I started targeting android O in my project I get an error when calling `startActivityForResult(intent, int, Bundle)` with the error saying it can only be called from group id com.android.support.

Gradle:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:26.0.0'
```

Comment: Sounds like you should [file a bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=192731&template=842428).

Comment: @Nick Mowen are you using support based fragment ..FragmentActivity -Base class for activities that want to use the support-based Fragment and Loader APIs.

Comment: @ZohraKhan I am using it on AppCompatActivity inside of a views onClick method

Answer (score 19):

It's a bit late but I've found a workaround. 
I tried `ActivityCompat.startActivityForResult(Activity, intent, int, Bundle);` and the warning is gone!

Comment: Removing warnings if bad practice, this is the correct answer

Answer (score 5):

Edit:

As per this [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64039135), this is a bug.
For a workaround, Add this comment above the line of code which gives the warning:

```
//noinspection RestrictedApi
```

Old Ans:

I hope you are not importing wrong library. [Fragment support library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/index.html) supports fragment for devices running versions prior to Android3.0.

As per this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15318518/android-activity-vs-fragmentactivity) in SO

> Also remember to use Activity if you are using android.app.Fragment; 
>       use FragmentActivity if you are using android.support.v4.app.Fragment. 
>       Never attach a android.support.v4.app.Fragment to an android.app.Activity,
>       as this will cause an exception to be thrown.

`android.app.Fragment` is different than `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`.

The support library one is annotated `@RestrictTo(LIBRARY_GROUP)`, and also `@hide` - it's not meant to be a public API.

Comment: The thing is that I am not even using fragments where this is happening. I will add my gradle imports to the post

Comment: Not working in Android Studio 3.1.
Md. Didarul islam's answer is working

Answer (score 1):

Use this in build.gridle

android {
  lintOptions {
    disable 'RestrictedApi'
  }
}

caution: Using this may hide other errors in your project. It will suppresses all errors of this type.